# Ошибка R.drawable cannot be resolved to a variable в Android App Project

Tags: android-sdk, android, ресурсы, изображения

Скопировал через Eclipse файлы *1.jpg*, *2.jpg*, *3.jpg* в папку ***res/drawable-hdpi***, далее в коде пишу

```
image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.1);
```

Eclipse показывает ошибку **R.drawable cannot be resolved to a variable**. Как пофиксить?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Переименовать. Нельзя использовать цифры и большие буквы.

Comment: вообще цифры? или вот можно d1.jpg ?

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat ограничения те же что и для Java идентификаторов, стало быть d1.jpg можно